# Merge orgmode tables vertically

Tags: org-mode

Is it possible to append a table below another? I am looking for something like [this](https://eschulte.github.io/org-scraps/scraps/2011-05-14-append-tables.html) but in the following form:

```
#+name: tbl1
| a | 1 |
| b | 2 |
#+name: tbl2
| c | 3 |
| d | 4 |
```

I am expecting to get this:

```
| a | 1 |
| b | 2 |
| c | 3 |
| d | 4 |
```

From my search I found [lob-tables-operations](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/examples/lob-table-operations.html) but it seems to me that it's not well documented and likely not under maintenance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was quite straight forward based on [this example](https://eschulte.github.io/org-scraps/scraps/2011-05-14-append-tables.html). I just used of `mapcan` instead of `mapcar`

```
** append tables
   :PROPERTIES:
   :DATE:     2015-06-19
   :END:
#+name: table-names
- first-table
- second-table
- third-table

#+name: first-table
| a | 1 |
| b | 2 |
|---+---|

#+name: second-table
| c | 3 |
| d | 4 |
|---+---|

#+name: third-table
| f | 5 |
| g | 6 |
|---+---|


#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :var table-names=table-names
(mapcan #'org-babel-ref-resolve table-names)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
| a | 1 |
| b | 2 |
|---+---|
| c | 3 |
| d | 4 |
|---+---|
| f | 5 |
| g | 6 |
|---+---|
```